# Does this set of symmetric matrices form a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $A$ be a real symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. Let $1 \leq i < j \leq n$ and $1 \leq k < \ell \leq n$. Let $A'$ be the submatrix of $A$ consisting of rows $i,...,j$ and columns $k,...,\ell$. Is the set of all such matrices $A$ with rank$(A')=1$ a smooth manifold?

Comment: Can you write equations for the set of all those matrices as a subset of the vector space of all real symmetric matrices?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

(Partial answer) Let first answer an easier question: Let $M$ be the set of all real $k\times l$ matrices with rank$(A) = 1$. Then if $A \in M$, $A$ is controlled by one column: Let $M_j$, $j=1, \cdots, l$, be the subset with nonzero $j-th$ column. Then 
$$M_j \cong \big(\mathbb R^{k}\setminus \{0\}\big) \times \mathbb R^{l-1}$$

where $\mathbb R^{k}\setminus \{0\}$ corresponds to the $j-th$ column vector $\vec a_j$ and all other vectors are $\vec a_ic_i \vec a_j$, where $c_i \in \mathbb R$ and $i\neq j$.

Now consider $M_i \cap M_j$, $i<j$, which is the set of all $A \in M$ with nonzero $i$-th and $j$-th columns. Let's say on $M_j$, $A$ is given by 
$$(\vec a_j, c_1, \cdots c_{j-1}, c_{j+1} \cdots, c_l)$$
That is,  whenever $k\neq j$, we have $\vec a_k = c_k a_j$. So $\vec a_i = c_i \vec a_j$

$$\Rightarrow a_k = \frac{c_k}{c_k} a_i$$

whenever $k\neq j$. Then on $M_i$ $A$ is given by

$$\bigg(c_i \vec a_j, \frac{c_1}{c_j}, \cdots, \frac{c_{i-1}}{c_i}, \frac{c_{i+1}}{c_i}, \cdots, \frac{c_{j-1}}{c_i}, \frac{1}{c_i}, \frac{c_{j+1}}{c_i}, \cdots ,\frac{c_l}{c_i}\bigg)$$

This map is obviously differntiable, thus $M$ is a smooth manifold (acutally a submanifold in $\mathbb R^{kl}$) with dimensional $k+l-1$.

Now note that your space can be identified with some subspace of $M$. (Fixing some $i$ and $j$, then consider $j-i = k$ and $l-k = "l"$ (sorry for the bad choice of notation)).

Indeed, the set of all such $A$ can be given by zero set of several smooth functions on $M$. For example, let $n=4$ and your are considering all the submatrix $i=1, j=2,k = 1, l = 3$. Then $M$ is the $2 + 3-1$-dimensional manifold constructed above, and the space you are considering is the zero set of $f (A) = a_{12} - a_{21}$ in $M$.

I think it will not be difficult (but messy) then to check that your space is really a smooth manifold.